# Cannot read from 2nd SATA data drive connected via SATA docking station

Tags: 10.10, drive

Installed 10.10 this week on dual boot system. Everything else works fine but cannot read from 2nd SATA drive with all my data.

Same drive works normally when booted to Windows XP.

Interesting part is that I can see the drive in Ubuntu Disk Manager, can read all its attributes, can test it, shows up in Disk Manager, Storage Device Manager and Mount Manager, and can mount it, even change attributes; it appears healthy but does not show up in "Computer" or anywhere else that it can be accessed.

The drive is connected via an external e-SATA docking station which is connected to a SATA port on the motherboard.

---

Screen captures:

http://www.smallwood.com.au/ubuntu/

---

(FYI DISK THAT CAN'T BE ACCESSED IS SDC5)

rob@rob-GA-VM900M:~$ mount

/dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw)

none on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)

none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)

none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)

none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)

none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)

none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)

none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

/dev/sda1 on /media/142C6BDD2C6BB87E type fuseblk 
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

/dev/sdb1 on /media/sdb1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/rob/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=rob)

rob@rob-GA-VM900M:~$ ^C

rob@rob-GA-VM900M:~$

Comment: Please attach output of `mount`, when disk is mounted.

Comment: /dev/sda1 on /media/142C6BDD2C6BB87E type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096
try cd /media/142C6BDD2C6BB87E/
then ls -la

Answer (score 1):

Try from a terminal,

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc5 /mnt
```

If it works works,then great
If does not work, please paste the errors reported.

Also can you attach a screen shot similar to screenshot.png from disk utility, but this time after selecting the sdc5 partition. The current screen shot is for sdc1 which is extended partition holding sdc5. If you click on the "1.5 Transportable Media Drive" (this is sdc5) box in volumes, you will select sdc5 and it will show properties of sdc5. That will help us to determine the command to get it mounted and its properties.

The same screen should allow you to mount sdc5 from GUI mode,
If it shows "Mount Volume"  and "Check filesystem" once you selected sdc5 try both and see if you are able to mount from there.

Report any errors if it fails to mount it from there.

Comment: After typing in terminal:

sudo mount /dev/sdc5 /mnt

Error message: "you must specify the filesystem type"

Comment: The filesystem type as per screen shots is ntfs-3g, so command to try is sudo mount -t nfs-3g /dev/sdc5 /mnt. Also can you attach another screen shot similar to screenshot.png from disk utility, but this time after selecting the sdc5 partition. The current screen shot is for sdc1 which is extended partition holding sdc5. If you click down, you will select sdc5 and it will show properties of sdc5